# Why is my Swift function asking me for the wrong variables

Tags: ios, swift

I made a struct, and a function inside of it and I don't understand why it is asking me for the wrong parameters when I try to call it. Here is my function declaration:

```
struct UserInterfaceVariables {
    func applyCustomAnimation(view: AnimatableView, animationType: String, duration: Double, delay: Double, damping: CGFloat, velocity: CGFloat, force: CGFloat) {
        view.animationType = animationType
        view.duration = duration
        view.delay = delay
        view.damping = damping
        view.velocity = velocity
        view.force = force
    }
}
```

And in another view controller, I try to call it, it asks me for a "UserInterfaceVariables" parameter, but that isn't the type of parameter I want to input... I want to input the parameters from my function declaration ("animationType", etc...)

```
UserInterfaceVariables.applyCustomAnimation(UserInterfaceVariables)
```

Do note that the "UserInterfaceVariables" entry (in the parentheses) is the type of parameter it is expecting... i.e. this is what it looks like on Xcode:

[image]

Why is it not asking me for the parameters declared in my function definition ?

**EDIT 1** Tentative solution:

```
let userInterfaceVariables = UserInterfaceVariables()
applyCustomAnimation(view: ..., .....)
```

Comment: You're trying to call your method on the type itself instead of an instance of it

Comment: Oh ok, so should I do something that ressembles the edit I just made ? Declare an instance of UserInterfaceVariables() and then call the function that was defined inside the UserInterfaceVariables struct ?

Comment: If you want to be able to call the method on the type then you should declare the function as `static`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

### Issue

You are calling an instance method from a type. [Read more](http://www.codingexplorer.com/instance-methods-and-type-methods-in-swift/)

### Solution

Either create an instance of the struct like [iGongora](https://stackoverflow.com/a/35929208/2664437) pointed out, or mark the your method as `static`

```
static func applyCustomAnimation(view: AnimatableView, animationType: String, duration: Double, delay: Double, damping: CGFloat, velocity: CGFloat, force: CGFloat) {
    view.animationType = animationType
    view.duration = duration
    view.delay = delay
    view.damping = damping
    view.velocity = velocity
    view.force = force
}
```

Now you will be able to call the method correctly with your current code

Cheers

Comment: Thanks a lot, I'm still a beginner at all this so to be honest, I have no idea what static really means. Thanks for the explanation, I just tested it and it works like a charm.

Comment: You are welcome. Just practice and read [docs](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/Swift/Conceptual/Swift_Programming_Language/Methods.html) and you will be in good shape soon :)

Answer (score 2):

That's because you need to init the struct before use it and the parameter is telling you. Once you init your struct, the parameters will change.

Try `let userInterface = UserInterfaceVariables()` and then `userInterface.applyCustomAnimation(yourParameters)`